# How to start app from Google glass

Tags: google-glass

I have finished an app for Google glass and make it run well on it. But when I restart the Google glass, I can't find where my app is. Do anyone knows how to start an app without usb connecting to computer?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the section on [voice triggers](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/voice#starting_glassware) in the GDK documentation.

(Note that you do not need the `<input prompt="@string/glass_voice_prompt" />` line in your voice trigger XML if you do not want Glass to prompt you for additional speech before launching your activity.)